# How can I load an image before it's needed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization

I'm developing a website with an image gallery. There is a grid of images with dozens of thumbnails. When a user clicks on an image a div slides down from the top. That div's CSS gets edited with JavaScript to change the background-image.

My problem is that the div slides down, but the background image "flickers" in randomly. What I want is the div to slide down with the image already loaded. I'm not sure how to solve this problem because I think it would be unreasonable to pre-load every thumbnail's larger version when the user most likely won't click on them all.

Comment: If I undestand it correctly, you're trying to implement a _lightbox_. There are dozens of pre-made solutions online, why don't you use one of them?
You could start from https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image to base64 and enable it in src of the img tag, after that send in the dormulário.

this use example: https://hdtuto.com/article/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-jquery

Answer (score 0):

One way to preload images is to create an image object using javascript

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<img src="photo1.jpg" id="photo" />
```

Javascript:

```
var photo = document.getElementById("photo");
var loadImage = new Image();
loadImage.src = "YourSrc/image.jpg";
```

Last step, use this code in your event handler when you want to change to the preloaded image:

```
photo.src = loadImage.src;
```

If you are looking to preload **multiple** images use an array and a loop.

```
imageSrcs = ["imgsrc1.jpg", "imgsrc2jpg", "imgsrc3jpg"];
preloadedImages = [];

for(var i = 0; i < imgSrcs.length; i++)
 {
preloadedImages[i] = new Image();
preloadedImages[i].src = preloadedImages[i];
}
```